# What is the Redis command to search for an entry with specific field value?

Tags: redis

In Redis I've got a branch (cache:ID) and multiple hashes inside it (for instance some keys: `cache:123457`, `cache:563457`).

Entries have fields: `id` - aka primary key, and `sign` - just a label.

I want to search in my Redis and find all entries which has the field `sign` equal to `a`. The performance is not the question. I just need to verify that such entries exist. I understand that I need somehow to iterate through all entries, but cannot find a correct command(s) for this. I checked `KEYS` (KEYS cache:* - but what's next?), `SCAN` but had no luck with them. In SQL I would do this as follows: `select * from cache where sing='a'`. So I don't want to scan keys, I want to scan fields of all entries.

How can I do what I want? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello Alexander, what do you mean by branch ? Do you have `hash` keys some of them has field named `id`, `label` and you want to know which `hash` keys have `sign` field and `sign` equals to `a` ?

Comment: Hi @Ersoy I might be using incorrect name, but this is how it's called in Redis Commander tool. This [picture](https://prnt.sc/svzzkk) should visualize clearly what i'm talking about.

Comment: There are different fields thought.

Comment: In the picture you provided there is a `Type` column, it says hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis doesn't work like `RDBMs` and if you want to query like `select * from cache where sing='a'`, you may create [secondary indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes).

When you create a new `hash`, you also add to a `set` named by `hash value`. i will use `sign` prefix.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET firsthash id 1 sign a
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD sign:a firsthash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET secondhash id 2 sign b
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD sign:b secondhash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET thirdhash id 3 sign a
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD sign:a thirdhash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET fourthhash id 4 sign aa
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD sign:aa fourthhash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS sign:a
1) "thirdhash"
2) "firsthash"
```

When you delete the hash - delete also from the set.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL firsthash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SREM sign:a firsthash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS sign:a
1) "thirdhash"
```

When you need to update the value of hash field, first delete from the set and then add to the new one

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SREM sign:a thirdhash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET thirdhash sign newa
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL thirdhash
1) "id"
2) "3"
3) "sign"
4) "newa"
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD sign:newa thirdhash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS sign:newa
1) "thirdhash"
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you for guidance.